# How to Sub-Query CampaignMembers from Leads?

Tags: apex, campaign-member

I'm having an issue where when I subquery for CampaignMembers associated with leads, nothing is returned.  I am 100% certain that the leads I'm testing with have campaign members associated with them.

Here is what I'm testing with with apex anonymous:

```
List<Lead> leads = [select id, (select id, createdDate from campaignMembers) from Lead where id in ('00Q3200001Mmp6f')];
system.debug(loggingLevel.error, 'LEADS: ' + leads);

List<CampaignMember> members = [select id, createdDate, leadId, contactId, leadOrContactId from campaignMember where leadId = '00Q3200001Mmp6f'];
system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'campaign members: ' + members);
```

And here is the debug log:

```
14:52:14.1 (26035863)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|ERROR|LEADS: (Lead:{Id=00Q3200001Mmp6fEAB})
14:52:14.1 (38020671)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|ERROR|campaign members: (CampaignMember:{Id=00v3200002YgwOFAAZ, CreatedDate=2017-05-25 03:30:57, LeadId=00Q3200001Mmp6fEAB, LeadOrContactId=00Q3200001Mmp6fEAB, RecordTypeId=012320000001GbPAAU}, CampaignMember:{Id=00v3200002WEk0kAAD.....
```

Why are no campaign member records being returned in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are being returned; the debug statement doesn't include sub-queries. Try the following Apex Code:

```
List<Lead> leads = [select id, (select id, createdDate from campaignMembers) from Lead where id in ('00Q3200001Mmp6f')];
for(Lead leadRecord: leads) {
    system.debug(leadRecord.CampaignMembers);
}
```